# Magento site got messed up after trying to install an extension

Tags: magento2, extensions

I was trying to install extension "Magento 2 Indian GST Extension" and after I follow command, my website got messed up. See https://equosinfotech.in

I dont know what is the issue. And how to solve it.

Need help as I am new to magento.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f

chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
```

Try this commands.

Comment: I did actually , all these commands.

Comment: chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
@Jack

Comment: need to give permission to pub folder,

Comment: Sorry, but I will always downvote any answer including chmod 777

Comment: Webserver user permissions should be enough.